# Finding union and intersection within a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with a list of movies and actors in the movies, and I'm trying to write two functions: one that finds all actors in any two movies, and another that finds only actors in both of the movies. This is what I have:

```
def allActors(movie1,movie2):
    dictionary1=makeDictionaryFromFile()
    actor1=[]
    actor2=[]
    if movie1 in dictionary1.keys() and movie2 in dictionary1.keys():
        actor1=dictionary1[movie1]
        actor2=dictionary1[movie2]
        return actor1+actor2

def actorsOverlap(movie1,movie2):
    dictionary1=makeDictionaryFromFile()
    actor1=[]
    actor2=[]
    if movie1 in dictionary1.keys() and movie2 in dictionary1.keys():
        actor1=dictionary1[movie1]
        actor2=dictionary1[movie2]
        actors=[]
        for name in actor1:
            if name in actor2:
                actors=actors.append([name])
                return actors
```

The dictionary looks like this:

```
{'Harry Potter': ['Daniel Radcliffe', 'Emma Thompson', 'Alan Rickman'], 'Sense and Sensibility': ['Emma Thompson', 'Alan Rickman', 'Hugh Grant']}
```

so the first should give:

```
['Daniel Radcliffe', 'Emma Thompson', 'Alan Rickman','Emma Thompson', 'Alan Rickman', 'Hugh Grant']
```

(I haven't figured out how to get 'Emma Thompson' and 'Alan Rickman' to only print once)

and the second should give:

```
['Emma Thompson', 'Alan Rickman']
```

This is part of a longer project, that looks like this so far (with suggested edits):

```
from Myro import *
def makeDictionaryFromFile():
   dictionary1={}
   try:
       infile = open("films.txt","r")
       nextLineFromFile = infile.readline().rstrip('\r\n')
       while (nextLineFromFile != ""):
            line = nextLineFromFile.split(",")
            first=line[0]
            dictionary1[first]=line[1:]
            nextLineFromFile = infile.readline().rstrip('\r\n')
    except:
        print ("File not found! (or other error!)")
    return dictionary1

def makeReverseDictionary():
    dictionary1 ={}
    dictionary1 = makeDictionaryFromFile()
    dictionary2 = {}
    for k,vlist in dictionary1.iteritems():
        for v in vlist:
            dictionary2.setdefault(v,[]).append(k)
    return dictionary2

 def allActors(movie1,movie2):
    dictionary1 = makeDictionaryFromFile()
    if movie1 in dictionary1.keys() and movie2 in dictionary1.keys():
        return list(set(dictionary1[movie1]+ dictionary1[movie2]))
    return None

def actorsOverlap(movie1,movie2):
    dictionary1 = makeDictionaryFromFile()
    if movie1 in dictionary1.keys() and movie2 in dictionary1.keys():
        return list(set(dictionar1.values) & set(dictionary2.values()))

def coactors(actor):
    dictionary2 = makeDictionaryFromFile()
    (some code)

def menu():
    answer=askQuestion("choose one",["create actor-title dictionary", "create title-actor dictionary", "find all actors in two movies", "find all overlapping actors in two movies","find all actors not in both movies","find all co-actors of an actor","Nothing, I wish to quit"])
    if answer == ("create actor-title dictionary"):
        answer = 1
    elif answer == ("create title-actor dictionary"):
        answer = 2
    elif answer == ("find all actors in two movies"):
        answer = 3
    elif (answer == "find all overlapping actors in two movies"):
        answer = 4
    elif (answer == "find all co-actors of an actor"):
        answer = 5
    elif (answer == "Nothing, I wish to quit"):
        answer = 6
    return answer

def main():
    choice = menu()
    while (choice != 6):
        if (choice == 1):
            dictionary=makeDictionaryFromFile()
            print (dictionary)
        elif (choice == 2):
            dictionary=makeReverseDictionary()
            print (dictionary)
        elif (choice == 3):
            movie1=input("first movie")
            movie2=input("second movie")
            actors=allActors(movie1, movie2)
            print (actors)
        elif (choice == 4):
            movie1=input("first movie")
            movie2=input("second movie")
            actors=actorsOverlap(movie1,movie2)
            print (actors)
        elif (choice == 5):
            actor=input("actor's name")
            try:
                coactors=coactors(actor)
                print (coactors)
            except:
                 print ("Error. Check spelling and try again.")
        choice = menu()
```

Comment: Use a set to store only unique items and to perform operations like intersection, union etc.

Comment: return list(set(actor1+actor2))

Comment: thanks!, the second one doesn't work at all though

Comment: if i have questions on different parts of this project, should i post them here, or ask a new question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dictionary1=makeDictionaryFromFile() # make dictionary1 one time , it will be availabe for all function
def allActors(movie1,movie2):
    if movie1 in dictionary1.keys() and movie2 in dictionary1.keys():
        return list(set(dictionary1[movie1]+ dictionary1[movie2]))

def actorsOverlap(movie1,movie2):
    if movie1 in dictionary1.keys() and movie2 in dictionary1.keys():
        return list(set(dictionar1[movie1]) & set(dictionary2[movie2]))
```

`set` produces unordered Unique list

`set1 & set 2` will give you all common element,no need of creating extra actor1 and actor2 list.

Comment: check the code I have edited for your original code, if you havent got the concept, feel free to ask

Comment: You left out a closing parenthesis in the last line, and it still doesn't work. Should I post the rest of my code, and see if there's something else going on?

Comment: ok, i found the problem with my dictionary, but now i get `builtin_function_or_method is not iterable` in `return list(set(dictionary2.values) & set(dictionary2.values()))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html).

By definition, a set only contains unique elements.

Here is a rough rewrite of your code to use sets (assuming the dictionaries still hold lists):

```
def allActors(movie1,movie2):
    dictionary1=makeDictionaryFromFile()
    actor1 = set(dictionary1.get(movie1, []))
    actor2 = set(dictionary1.get(movie2, []))
    return actor1.union(actor2)

def actorsOverlap(movie1,movie2):
    dictionary1=makeDictionaryFromFile()
    actor1 = set(dictionary1.get(movie1, []))
    actor2 = set(dictionary1.get(movie2, []))
    return actor1.intersection(actor2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` and `set` to find union of values and interestions

```
d={'Harry Potter': ['Daniel Radcliffe', 'Emma Thompson', 'Alan Rickman'], 'Sense and Sensibility': ['Emma Thompson', 'Alan Rickman', 'Hugh Grant']}

union= reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, d.values())
inter= reduce(lambda x,y:list(set(x) & set(y)), d.values())
print inter, union
```

Output:

> ```
> ['Emma Thompson', 'Alan Rickman'] 
> ['Daniel Radcliffe', 'Emma Thompson', 'Alan Rickman', 'Emma Thompson', 'Alan Rickman', 'Hugh Grant']
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I would re-write your functions as follows:

```
def allActors(movie1, movie2):
    dictionary1 = makeDictionaryFromFile()
    if movie1 in dictionary1.keys() and movie2 in dictionary1.keys():
        return set(dictionary1[movie1] + dictionary1[movie2])
    return None

def actorsOverlap(movie1,movie2):
    dictionary1 = makeDictionaryFromFile()
    if movie1 in dictionary1.keys() and movie2 in dictionary1.keys():
        return set(dictionary1[movie1]).intersection(set(dictionary1[movie2]))
    return set()
```

Comment: I just get "None" still

Comment: and the second just returns an empty set

Comment: That means that either your makeDictionaryFromFile function is creating an empty dictionary or the movies you inputed are not in the dictionary...

Comment: but I had it before so it printed the dictionary before making the set, and it printed the dictionary, so that part must work, and I checked to make sure the inputs were actually in the dictionary.

Comment: never mind, it was accessing the wrong dictionary and i'm an idiot